# Can't find current position of an GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying myself in unity and I like to code a little game in it. I want to make a script which displays on a text above the game the current score. For this I like to use the transform.position script but if I use it it doesnt update the current position. It only shows the positon of the GameObject at the beginning of the scene. 
How can I change it the show the current scene each frame and displays it on the screen on the text field?

```cs
    public Transform tf;
    public Text textSoore; 

     void Start()
     {

     }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        tf = GetComponent<Transform>();
        textSoore = GetComponent<Text>();
        textSoore.text = tf.


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

first off, you don't need to call GetComponent, you can just use lowercase transform - I believe its also cached so a bit faster.

Regarding the core of your question, Text component takes a string as an input to textSoore.text, and you are trying to feed it a reference to transform. In this case you should be doing

```
 textSoore.text = transform.position.ToString();
```

While the 'to string' method can often be ommited (it an implicit, default call that often works), but looking at this form should make more sense. Many cases of errors are very easy to spot and prevent because of how C# is a stronlgly typed language, string=transform doens't make sense, while 'get vector3 postition from transform and convert it to string' does